# Downloading File on Google Drive to Run Macro

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get a .vbs to download files from google drive as I have had it working as a macro inside excel. It would just be overall easier without needing to go into excel to run the script. I have tried to Frankenstein the working code within the macro which downloads the file to downloads with some other but have got lost. I am still a rookie so if the code is less than ideal would appreciate some feedback.

As a note: The userprofile was attempted to be set as variable for multiple users with differently mapped download folders to still run it.

Ran macro in excel which achieved downloading the file. 
Tried to create .vbs with similar code and failed

```
Option Explicit

Dim FileNum
Dim FileData
Dim MyFile
Dim WHTTP
Dim strDisplayName 
Dim oShell
Dim strHomeFolder
Dim vbDirectory
Dim dir

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

'Set strDisplayName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set objAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
'Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objAD.UserName)
'strDisplayName = objUser.DisplayName


On Error Resume Next
    Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
    End If
On Error GoTo 0

MyFile = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hx5DymjrhaiM8Rb7NMP_Sde_JU2N2Rau"

WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
WHTTP.send
'On Error Resume Next
FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

If Dir(strHomeFolder & "\Downloads", vbDirectory) = Empty Then MkDir strHomeFolder & "\Downloads"

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strHomeFolder & "\Downloads\External Linking.xlsm", 0, True)
        'D:\Users\cdoyle\Desktop\External linking.xlsm
        'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hx5DymjrhaiM8Rb7NMP_Sde_JU2N2Rau
        '"C:\Users\ciara\OneDrive\BayswaterBridge.xlsm"'
xlApp.Run "BridgeHit"

'xlbook.Save False
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

'WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Keep getting some errors on If Dir(

line and seem to be chasing my tail.

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot use `Dir` (and `MkDir`) in VBScript. Use `FileSystemObject` instead. Tons of examples available out there.